# Python pandas how increase +1 end of each sku?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an pandas dataframe like this:

```
   product name             color                 sku
   
Men regular T-Shirt    White, Black, Orange      #VDY45P
Men  T-Shirt            Black, Orange            #VFY55P
```

my expected result will be like this:

Basically I want to add +1 end of my sku for related product.

```
 product name             color                 sku
   
Men regular T-Shirt    White                 #VDY45P-01
Men regular T-Shirt    Black                 #VDY45P-02
Men regular T-Shirt    Orange                #VDY45P-03 
Men  T-Shirt           Black                 #VFY55P-01
Men  T-Shirt           Orange                #VFY55P-02
```

Comment: Please do not post several times the same question. The answer is in the duplicate, you need to use `df.explode('color')`.

Comment: @mozway You didn't understood my question and it's not an duplicate question. I know I can use  'df.explode('color')` it will expand the row but not increment +1 for relate product like `#VDY45P-01`

Comment: see my second product have two variant color. so the sku will be somethings like this  `VFY55P-01` for black and `VFY55P-02` for orange

Comment: Ok I see, my bad, but that why it's important to provide code and a detailed description, not just to dump the input/output. I reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`explode` the column, and add the `cumcount` value per group:

```
(df
 .assign(color=lambda d: d['color'].str.split(',\s*'))
 .explode('color')
 .assign(sku=lambda d: d['sku']+'-'+d.groupby(level=0) 
                                     .cumcount().add(1)
                                     .astype(str).str.zfill(2))
)
```

Output:

```
          product name   color         sku
0  Men regular T-Shirt   White  #VDY45P-01
0  Men regular T-Shirt   Black  #VDY45P-02
0  Men regular T-Shirt  Orange  #VDY45P-03
1          Men T-Shirt   Black  #VFY55P-01
1          Men T-Shirt  Orange  #VFY55P-02
```

Comment: mozway Thanks for your help. It's working. can you please explain your third line of code. So we can understand how it's working.  what groupby,astype,zfill doing here?

Comment: Explode duplicates the indices, so we group by those to get the cumcount, add 1, convert the integers to string, fill with zeros to have 2 digits.